# how to add page number (page number of total pages) numbers in pagination?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I was able to create pagination for my table. Now i want to add page number on the bottom of my table(like page number of Total pages ). But i kinda struggle to do that. Anybody have any idea? Thanks

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" extensions="DispatcherContactNewController">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbs}" var="p">
            <tr class="lnkdsble" ><apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/></tr>
            <apex:column value="{!p.RecordTypeId}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!p.Createddate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
        </apex:panelGrid>


    </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public class DispatcherContactNewController {

    public DispatcherContactNewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setpb {
        get{
            if (setpb == null) {
                setpb = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, Createddate FROM Product_Brief__c])
                                                           );
            }
            return setpb;
        }
        set;
    }

    public List<Product_Brief__c>getpbs() {
        return (List<Product_Brief__c>)setpb.getrecords();
    }

    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return setpb.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return setpb.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return setpb.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    public void first() {
        setpb.first();
    }

    public void last() {
        setpb.last();
    }


    public void previous() {
        setpb.previous();
    }


    public void next() {
        setpb.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an idea and it involves the `getPageSize()` and `getResultSize()` methods along with a little math. Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Add following code in your VF page :

`<apex:outputText value="Page {!pageNumber} of {!CEILING(ResultSize /
PageSize)}" />`

where "ResultSize"variable indicates how many records are in the list in total, and "PageSize" indicates the number of records displayed per page.

Answer (score 2):

controller....

```
Public Integer getTotalPages(){
        pages = recNum/recLimit;
        return (Integer)pages.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }
```

// here recNum is total no. of rec and recLimit is no of records to be shown on page

vf......

```
  apex:outputLabel value=" page {!pageNum} of {!totalPages} " />
```

// here pageNum is get set integer var.. that is 0 at initialize and pageNum++ on each next call and pageNum-- on each previous button call !!!
I hope it helps!!!